# exit trades at specific time [pine script]

Tags: pine-script

In my strategy, If StopLoss or takeProfit is not hit then I will close the trade by 15:00 .
and I will also not enter trades beyond 12:30.

with that logic. I coded this block but doesn't seem to be working.

```
//Timing details , If an exit is not hit, then close the trade by 3PM exchange time.
exitTime = ((hour >= 15) and (minute >= 1))
//Don't enter after 12:30
lateEntry = ((hour >= 12) and (minute >= 30))
if (inGoodRange and strongCandle and breachS3 and notInTrade and timeperiod and not lateEntry)
    takeProfit = high + TP
    strategy.entry("long",strategy.long)
    strategy.exit("exit","long",stop=stopLoss,limit=R3)
    strategy.exit("exit","long",stop=stopLoss,limit=takeProfit)
    if(exitTime)
        strategy.exit("exit","long",limit=close)
```

Requesting Help.

Comment: I tried adding this line too
exitTime = (hour(time) == 15 and minute(time) >= 01)

and then checking if exitTime is TRUE to exit the trade. But that doesn't seem to work either

Comment: any help would be deeply appreciated. I'm not sure if this is a bug in my code or the API itself. I've scoured the net to figure out the problem. but many seem to have this issue with strategy.exit()